# How to make my App modular?

Tags: java, android

Hi and thanks for your attention.

I have an Android App (Java) whose code is growing (and eventually will need to grow more and more).

So I have to face the fact that I have make it somehow modular to make it manageable.

So I am here to ask some advice on how to go about it.

Basically the Apps consists of 2 screens, lets' call them A and B.

The App starts with screen A, which is a quiz, if the user responds correctly the screen B is displayed, showing the results; if the user wants to go on and take another quiz the App switches again to screen A, and so on in an infinite loop.

Please can you give me some advice no how to make this app more modular, to avoid all the code written in 'onCreate()'.

In particular how could I implement communication between the modules: how the Quiz module would communicate to the main and ask to switch the screen from A to B; how would the actions performed on screen B would communicate again to the main and ask to switch again to A.

I know it is a very open question, I am looking for some guidance, any suggestion very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For communications between screens, you could use sending messages or better **[Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)**. If you change something on screen B, it call screen A method, that do something.

Generally, for your problem, look at design patterns. Some of them could be usefull and they are widely supported in Java.

I am not very familiar with Android, but iOS has notifications (similar to triggers). Maybe something like that exist also for Android.